# ASP.NET DropDownList control doesn't postback correctly inside of UserControl

Tags: asp.net

I have a situation where a `DropDownList` control is not posting back correctly.  The `AutoPost` property is set to true, so the postback does happen, but the `SelectedValue` is not set to the correct value.  In addition, the `onSelectedIndexChanged` event doesn't fire.  The exact same code works perfect fine on an ASPX page, but does not work in a ASCX control.

I have tried all the obvious things, I hope, trying to figure this one out, but no luck so far.  I have even investigated what comes back in `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]` and `__EVENTARGUMENT`.  `__EVENTTARGET` does point to the drop down list, but the argument is empty.

Can the folks of StackOverflow help lead me in the right direction to debug this issue.  Of course, it is further complicated by master pages and the usual over-complication of ASP.NET.  Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="testDrop" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        EnableViewState="true" onselectedindexchanged="testDrop_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="1">1</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="2">2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

And here is the generated html:

```
<select id="ctl00_MainContent_rptAccordion_ctl00_statControl_testDrop" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$MainContent$rptAccordion$ctl00$statControl$testDrop\',\'\')', 0)" name="ctl00$MainContent$rptAccordion$ctl00$statControl$testDrop">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you post the code behind of the ASCX? It would be useful to know if you have any code in the Page_Load that mucks with this control.

Comment: Should I understand that the Postback DOES occur on index change of the drop down , but that the testDrop_SelectedIndexChanged() method is never called?

Answer (score 0):

This often happens when you re-poulate the DropDownList on the postback. This invalidates any selection. In your case, it could be that the ascx control is being recreated. Are you using LoadControl(...) to load your user control?

Comment: Tejs: The Page_Load on the Page does some data binding, but nothing extreme.  On the control the Page_Load is empty.

Comment: Radu: Yes, that is correct.  No on the LoadControl, the code is coded into an ItemTemplate in the main page:

       <ItemTemplate>
                            <ctl:details runat="server" ID="statControl" />
       </ItemTemplate>

Comment: Radu: The other odd part about it is that the Request.Form[control.UniqueID] has the actual correct value, it is just not being bound back to the control.

Comment: What about the data binding on the control that contains the ItemTemplate? When does this occur? It would help if you posted the code behind of your control and page that hosts it

Comment: Daniel: That is happening in the page_load of the page